# Exported anonymous function name is missing after typescript compilation

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript code:

```
const hasName = () => {};
console.log("hasName.name", hasName.name);

function hasName2() {};
console.log("hasName2.name", hasName2.name);

export const noName = () => {};
console.log("noName.name", noName.name);
```

produces the following result:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const hasName = () => { };
console.log("hasName.name", hasName.name);
function hasName2() { }
;
console.log("hasName2.name", hasName2.name);
exports.noName = () => { };
console.log("noName.name", exports.noName.name);
```

with tsconfig:

```
{"compilerOptions":{"target":"esnext","outDir":"build","module":"commonjs"}}
```

The log output is

```
hasName.name hasName
hasName2.name hasName2
noName.name
```

TypeScript compiler seems to omit the exported anonymous function name. Babel (7 rc2) keeps the name:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.noName = void 0;

var hasName = function hasName() {};
console.log("hasName.name", hasName.name);

function hasName2() {}
console.log("hasName2.name", hasName2.name);

var noName = function noName() {};
exports.noName = noName;
console.log("noName.name", noName.name);
```

The log output is

```
hasName.name hasName
hasName2.name hasName2
noName.name noName
```

Is there a way to have TS keep the names?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have TS keep the names

No. Not using TS.

*You can* use Babel with TypeScript https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-typescript.html However I recommend staying away from `.name` introspection anyways and just use TS as is.

Comment: here's why I asked: when migrating from JS to TS I had `const X: Read.StatelessComponent = () => ...` that has now lost its display name (e.g. in jest snapshots). I assume this is intentional by TS?